# Colimits in the category of formal schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an admissible ring such that $A = \varprojlim A_i$ is the limit of a system of discrete rings $A_i$. Is it true that $\mathop{\mathrm{Spf}}(A) = \varinjlim \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}(A_i)$ in the category of formal schemes? Since the functor $A \mapsto \mathop{\mathrm{Spf}}(A)$ from the opposite category of the category of admissible rings to the category of formal schemes is only right adjoint, I am not sure whether it commutes with colimits.

Another question is that let $\mathcal I \to \mathfrak{Sch}: i \mapsto X_i$ be a diagram in the category of schemes, then under what conditions does the colimit $\varinjlim X_i$ exists in the category of formal schemes.